# HTML5 always show the video control panel

Tags: html

I want to make the html5 `<video>` element's control panel always visible, and the play/pause button always hidden. I tried this:

```
<style>
    video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
        display: flex !important;
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
    video::-webkit-media-controls-overlay-play-button {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

The play/pause button is hidden, but the control panel stays default. What is the easiest way to do this?

P.S: I want this because I will use that `<video>` element as a recorder (with RecordRTC). So a recorder doesn't need a play/pause button. I will handle start/stop recording with different `<button>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the correct code to remove the play button. You should be able to make the video controls show and hide by inserting or removing the controls attribute:

```
<!-- Show Controls-->
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<!-- Hide Controls -->
<video width="320" height="240">
```

Comment: yes the `controls` attribute enables the control panel but the panel stays at its default behavior. by default behavior i mean fade out after hovering out. what i need is, when i hover out from the player, the control panel will still be visible.

Comment: OK, I see. Have you tried adding and removing the controls attribute button on the fly?